# OSX Mavericks Root User

Tags: macos, permission, root

I know it is possible to enable root user and then logging in as the root user. But is it possible to get root access with your admin account in OSX Mavericks?

It is kinda annoying to always type the password whenever you are installing stuff and using the terminal.

Last resort would be to always login as the root user?

Comment: I logging once into root with `sudo -s` really to much for you ?

Comment: What if you install a lot of software? You have to enter your password every time. Yes, that is too much for me. I bet I'm not the only one with the problem. I might be wrong though.

Comment: That's what `sudo -s` prevents you to do by creating a shell root session.

Answer (score 9):

`sudo` asks for the admin password only if you haven't used the command in the last 15 minutes or so. For extended root sessions I usually run `sudo -s` to create a new shell with root privileges.

Comment: That's a good solution, noted.

Comment: Alternately, you could do `sudo -v` periodically. That'll reset the timer to 15 minutes (only prompting for your password if it's already expired). You might also edit the `sudoers` file and raise the time limit (don't raise it _too_ high, though).

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically speaking, you could add your admin account into the `wheel` group, then use `visudo` to edit the `sudoers` file to allow your user account to execute commands as root. Not only would you have root privileges automatically in Terminal, it would also apply to the GUI as well (no more entering passwords when installing packages or unlocking preferences). **However, granting root access to any account other than the root user is a Bad Idea and would be the [Wrong Thing](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/W/Wrong-Thing.html) to do.** The security ramifications of doing this are extreme, and could seriously mess up your system if you don't know what you're doing (and even if you do).

But you did want to know if it was possible.

Comment: That's not how `wheel` works.  Being in group `wheel` would give you access to gid 0, not uid 0.  `wheel` is generally used on BSD (though not OS X by default) to restrict who *can* `su`/`sudo` to `root`, but does not automatically confer rights.  cf. http://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2007/07/19/the-wheel-group/

Comment: You could always set your account's uid to 0; there's nothing preventing multiple accounts sharing a uid on Unix.  That said, this is an absolutely, really, completely, totally, and utterly *terrible* idea.

Comment: @zigg Thanks for the correction--I was thinking of <a href="http://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2007/07/19/the-wheel-group/#comment-941">this line</a> being changed to allow the specified user to execute commands as root.

Comment: On OS X, the `admin` group actually does have `sudo` rights without all the `wheel` etc.  You'll have this group membership if your account has the "Allow user to administer this computer" box ticked.  cf. `/etc/sudoers`, which you can't even look at unless you're `root` or in the `wheel` group.