# Any reason not to change the root shell to bash?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, iterm, root

The default shell for root (at least on Yosemite) is `/bin/sh`.  Would there be any problem to changing it to bash (or better yet zsh)?  As far as a I know bash at least is backward compatible.

I need a more robust shell to run things like [iTerm's shell integration](http://iterm2.com/shell_integration.html).

Comment: How do you become the root user. I use the command `sudo bash`.

Comment: or `sudo -s` (which uses the value of `$SHELL` to spawn a root shell)

Comment: After taking a stab at answering this, I'm finding it hard to see what robust shell has to do with a practical problem. Is this hypothetical or are you facing a specific error?

Comment: If you are looking for help in getting iTerm shell integration working with `sh`  (because you currently get a `Your shell, /bin/sh, is not supported yet. Only tcsh, zsh, bash, and fish are supported. Sorry!` error when following the instructions on the iTerm site), please ask a new question for this (or consider analyzing the code of the curl'ed scripts and adapting it for `sh` the entry exam for running root shells :-)).

Comment: @patrix nailed it - Q:"when am I ready for a root shell?" A: You will know when the time comes.

Comment: Thanks for the condescending responses bmike and @patrix.  I asked a simple question and was hoping for a simple answer.  You added nothing  other than discouraging yet another StackExchange user.  Might have been better if I had left the last sentence off, but hey.

Comment: Yikes. I'm not trying to be patronizing or condescending. My apologies if you took it thusly. I was trying to get at the root cause. A simple question isn't ideal per the site - see [help] on the standards to avoid comments being offered to help refine the "ask". Also, I wouldn't have spent the time to construct my answer if I didn't think your question deserved an answer and also to help many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of the shell is the only substantial difference I can see between `sh` and `bash` - if you look carefully at /bin/sh on OS X, it's really bash (perhaps compiled with a flag to make it know it's filling in for sh since the binaries are slightly different).

```
mac me$ md5 /bin/sh /bin/bash
MD5 (/bin/sh) = 2cc3c26641112c1bd0173f396b7d7662
MD5 (/bin/bash) = 5d7583d80e5314ac844eedc6d68c6cd7
mac me $ ls -l /bin/sh /bin/bash
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  628496 Aug 28 02:02 /bin/bash
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  632672 Aug 28 02:02 /bin/sh
mac me $ sh --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
manoa mac me $ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

So, if somehow iTerm is barfing on /bin/sh even though it's already bash, you could change shells. I'd say running things from your user with `sudo -H` is always better than enabling root, but that's a discussion for another thread:

- [Is it 'OK' to use the root user as a normal user?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192365/)
- [OSX Mavericks Root User](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124549/)

If you want to test the change:

- [Change my shell to a different bash version at /usr/local/bin/bash?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55989/change-my-shell-to-a-different-bash-version-at-usr-local-bin-bash)
- [chsh doesn't change $SHELL](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131942/chsh-doesnt-change-shell)

Comment: You may be interested in the results of `echo $SHELLOPTS` between `sh` and `bash`, also `shopt`. The biggest difference between the two is the invocation of rc files.

Comment: Well said @fd0 - `shopt` and $SHELLOPTS are crucial for fixing actual problems with portability of scripts and such. I fear I already am too far down the rabbit hole for a question on working around one tool's check though.